# Django search functionality - bug with search query of length 2

Tags: django, search

As I am an impressed reader of Stack Overflow I want to ask my first question here. Since I encountered a problem with a snippet and I do not know whether I made a mistake or it's a bug in the code I'm using.

I adapted this code for my own site:

http://blog.tkbe.org/archive/django-admin-search-functionality/

It works fine and it's really a great snippet.
But if my search query has length 2, I think that the results are not correct.

So for example if I search for "re" in first name and last name, I get the following results:

```
Mr. Tom Krem
Ms. Su Ker
```

Which is pretty strange. For queries with length > 2 I do not encounter this problem.
So maybe this post read somebody who is using the snippet above and can tell me whether he/she encounters the same problem.

If nobody else encounters the problem I know at least that I have a bug somewhere in my code. Maybe in the form I'm using, or something is messed up in the request context.

How can I solve this problem?

Edit 1:

## The inclusion tag:

```
from django import template
from crm.views import SEARCH_VAR

def my_search_form(context):
    return {
        'context': context,
        'search_var': SEARCH_VAR
    }

register = template.Library()
register.inclusion_tag('custom_utilities/my_search_form.html')(my_search_form)
```

## The `my_search_form.html`:

```
<div id="toolbar"><form 
      id="changelist-search" 
      action="" 
      method="get"> 
        <div><!-- DIV needed for valid HTML --> 
            <label 
              for="searchbar"><img src="{{ context.media_url }}/crm/img/search.png" 
              class="icon" 
              alt="Search" /></label> 
            <input 
              type="text" 
              size="40" 
              name="{{ search_var }}" 
              value="{{ context.query }}" 
              id="searchbar" /> 
            <input type="submit" value="Search" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div> 
<script 
  type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("searchbar").focus();
</script>
```

## The view:

```
@login_required
def crm_contacts(request):
    query = request.GET.get('q', '')
    #pass additional params to the SortHeaders function
    #the additional params will be part of the header <a href...>
    #e.g. use it for pagination / use it to provide the query string
    additional_params_dict = {'q': query}
    foundContacts = search_contact(request,query)
    sort_headers = SortHeaders(request, LIST_HEADERS, default_order_field=1, additional_params=additional_params_dict)
    if foundContacts is not None:
        contact_list = foundContacts.order_by(sort_headers.get_order_by())
    else:
        contact_list = Contact.objects.order_by(sort_headers.get_order_by())
    context = {
        'contact_list' : contact_list,
        'headers': list(sort_headers.headers()),
        'query' : query,
    }
    return render_to_response("crm/contact_list.html", context,
                           context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

## The contact search form:

```
#models
from crm.models import Contact
from django.db.models import Q

'''
A search form from
http://blog.tkbe.org/archive/django-admin-search-functionality/
adapted to search for contacts.
'''
def search_contact(request,terms=None):
    if terms is None:
        return Contact.objects.all()
    query = Contact.objects
    for term in terms:
        query = query.filter(
            Q(first_name__icontains=term)
            | Q(last_name__icontains=term))
    return query
```

Another edit:

I'm using this snippet to sort the table. Probably one should know this in order to understand the code posted above.

Since I can not post links (spam protection) I will try to explain where to find it. Go to Google. Type in: django snippet table sort

Then it should be the second hit. Sort table headers. snippet nr. 308.

Edit: Add the SortHeaders() function

```
ORDER_VAR = 'o'
ORDER_TYPE_VAR = 'ot'

class SortHeaders:
    """
    Handles generation of an argument for the Django ORM's
    ``order_by`` method and generation of table headers which reflect
    the currently selected sort, based on defined table headers with
    matching sort criteria.

    Based in part on the Django Admin application's ``ChangeList``
    functionality.
    """
    def __init__(self, request, headers, default_order_field=None,
            default_order_type='asc', additional_params=None):
        """
        request
            The request currently being processed - the current sort
            order field and type are determined based on GET
            parameters.

        headers
            A list of two-tuples of header text and matching ordering
            criteria for use with the Django ORM's ``order_by``
            method. A criterion of ``None`` indicates that a header
            is not sortable.

        default_order_field
            The index of the header definition to be used for default
            ordering and when an invalid or non-sortable header is
            specified in GET parameters. If not specified, the index
            of the first sortable header will be used.

        default_order_type
            The default type of ordering used - must be one of
            ``'asc`` or ``'desc'``.

        additional_params:
            Query parameters which should always appear in sort links,
            specified as a dictionary mapping parameter names to
            values. For example, this might contain the current page
            number if you're sorting a paginated list of items.
        """
        if default_order_field is None:
            for i, (header, query_lookup) in enumerate(headers):
                if query_lookup is not None:
                    default_order_field = i
                    break
        if default_order_field is None:
            raise AttributeError('No default_order_field was specified and none of the header definitions given were sortable.')
        if default_order_type not in ('asc', 'desc'):
            raise AttributeError('If given, default_order_type must be one of \'asc\' or \'desc\'.')
        if additional_params is None: additional_params = {}

        self.header_defs = headers
        self.additional_params = additional_params
        self.order_field, self.order_type = default_order_field, default_order_type

        # Determine order field and order type for the current request
        params = dict(request.GET.items())
        if ORDER_VAR in params:
            try:
                new_order_field = int(params[ORDER_VAR])
                if headers[new_order_field][1] is not None:
                    self.order_field = new_order_field
            except (IndexError, ValueError):
                pass # Use the default
        if ORDER_TYPE_VAR in params and params[ORDER_TYPE_VAR] in ('asc', 'desc'):
            self.order_type = params[ORDER_TYPE_VAR]

    def headers(self):
        """
        Generates dicts containing header and sort link details for
        all defined headers.
        """
        for i, (header, order_criterion) in enumerate(self.header_defs):
            th_classes = []
            new_order_type = 'asc'
            if i == self.order_field:
                th_classes.append('sorted %sending' % self.order_type)
                new_order_type = {'asc': 'desc', 'desc': 'asc'}[self.order_type]
            yield {
                'text': header,
                'sortable': order_criterion is not None,
                'url': self.get_query_string({ORDER_VAR: i, ORDER_TYPE_VAR: new_order_type}),
                'class_attr': (th_classes and ' class="%s"' % ' '.join(th_classes) or ''),
            }

    def get_query_string(self, params):
        """
        Creates a query string from the given dictionary of
        parameters, including any additonal parameters which should
        always be present.
        """
        params.update(self.additional_params)
        return '?%s' % '&amp;'.join(['%s=%s' % (param, value) \
                                     for param, value in params.items()])

    def get_order_by(self):
        """
        Creates an ordering criterion based on the current order
        field and order type, for use with the Django ORM's
        ``order_by`` method.
        """
        return '%s%s' % (
            self.order_type == 'desc' and '-' or '',
            self.header_defs[self.order_field][1],
        )
```

Comment: What is your database backend? PostgreSQL? MySQL? Could you post your adapted version of the code you point on the blog above?

Comment: i m using mysql. i will post the adapted version of the code below.

Comment: You really should have all the code you added as an answer as an edit to the question. I'm not trying to nitpick, it is just that you know just marked your question as answered (which reduces traffic to it, and the hope to get it answered), and confuses future readers in thinking that all that code is part of a solution to the question.

Comment: ok .. i tried to post it as a comment. but comments are restricted to 600 characters.. hmm.. could i mark the question somehow as unanswered? :D

Comment: Nope, don't post it as a comment. Comments are for short clarifications, nothing more. Edit your own question. There is an edit link right under the tags retag and flag. Edit the question, add the relevant code.

Comment: ok .. sorry its my first post here. now i know how to handle it. 

actually i saw that the query "mot" will return also a contact which has as first name "tom". thus there is some matching forward-reverse problem. the docu of __icontains says that it acts like a "like" statement. maybe thats the problem!? does the like statement also matches the reverse string?

Comment: No need to apologize. :-) I'm happy you figured it out.

Comment: And, no, the like statement shouldn't match the reverse string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run `manage.py shell` and then:

```
>>> from crm.models import Contact
>>> from django.db.models import Q
>>> list=Contact.objects.filter(Q(first_name__icontains='re')|Q(last_name__icontains='re'))
>>> print list
```

What is the output?

---

Edit: Right, so if you try:

```
>>> list=Contact.objects.filter(Q(first_name__icontains='mot')|Q(last_name__icontains='mot'))
>>> print list
```

(I'm trying to narrow down on the terms that are giving you problem and I saw your last comment)

What is the output?

---

Edit: If both of the above queries work in the shell, something else is modifying your queryset somewhere and adding some additional criteria...

Are you sure `sort_headers()` is not modifying the queryset with more than just an order by clause? Could you post `sort_headers()` to your question?

Comment: output is-> Mr. Tom Krem 

this would be correct! thus probably there is a problem in transfering the query string?

Comment: ok both the above queries work well. thus probably somewhere i probably add something to my query. i will check the code tomorrow. its to late now ;-) thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: i guess i found the problem. it is the term in query. it seems as each character is filtered for and added to the result set..!?

query = request.GET.get('q', '')
foundContacts = search_contact(request,query)
>>>
>>> queryresult = Contact.objects
>>> for term in query:
...         print term
...         queryresult = queryresult.filter(
...             Q(first_name__icontains=term)
...             | Q(last_name__icontains=term))
...
m
o
t
>>> print queryresult
[<Contact: Tom Tom>, <Contact: Tom Tom>, <Contact: Tom Tom>, <Contact: Tom Tom>, <Contact: Tom Tom>, <Contact: Tom Tom>, ...